# Error "Failed to execute goal" while trying to create a project with JSF

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, maven-plugin

I failed to execute goal `org.apache.maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree`.

I am using command in my cmd:

```
mvn archetype:create-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

I followed many solutions, but didn't find any solution for this.

[image]

Comment: I strongly suspect that there's more details in a log - or you can increase the verbosity to make sure there *are* more details in the log...

Comment: I added output in my cmd. please have a look

Comment: Have you considered re-running Maven with the -e switch?  Or the -X switch?

Comment: Yes i tried, not working. But can you elaborate how to use. so if i am doing any mistake i can recover.

Comment: I think there should be a space between `create` and `-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test`.

Comment: Can you try this - `mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test" "-DartifactId=helloworld"`  ?

Comment: @LittlePanda is right. Did you try to run "mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test -"... with space after 'create'? if you did, show the output.

Comment: @OhadR: The OP claims he is running the command with spaces. @ Rishi: Please update your question with the correct command you ran (use -e switch) and also then stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks LittlePanda its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for the issue is to use below command with quotes:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test" "-DartifactId=helloworld"
```

Comment: I think both the commands will work (with or without quotes). I posted this as an answer because this worked for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Maven couldn't find goal **create-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test**

Try to put space after **create**

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Comment: Maven said that it hadn't found goal create-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test in screenshot. If you added space after "create" I don't think output would be the same.